# pg_restore showing errors when specifying schema when backing up with pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have created two different dump files one without specifying the schema, another specifying the `public` schema

without specifying the public schema'

```
pg_dump -h IP_ADDRESS -p 5432 -U my_user -Fc my_db  > my_db_allschema.dump
```

and the pg_dump statement when specifying the public schema

```
pg_dump -h IP_ADDRESS -p 5432 -U my_user -Fc my_db -n public > my_db_publicschema.dump
```

When using pg_restore to restore the dump files, I get errors with the dump file that was generated when specifying the public schema.

```
postgres@debian:~$ pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432  -U my_user -d my_db my_db_publicschemaonly.dump
pg_restore: while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: from TOC entry 8; 2615 2200 SCHEMA public postgres
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  schema "public" already exists
Command was: CREATE SCHEMA public;


pg_restore: from TOC entry 212; 1259 18102 TABLE abandoned_url real_estate
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  function public.gen_random_uuid() does not exist
LINE 2:     id uuid DEFAULT public.gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL
                            ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Command was: CREATE TABLE public.abandoned_url (
    id uuid DEFAULT public.gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL
);
```

Looking at this statement that throws an error

```
CREATE TABLE public.abandoned_url (
        id uuid DEFAULT public.gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL
    );
```

The reason it's throwing an error is because pg_dump has put `public` before `gen_random_uuid()`, the following statement works fine when removing public before gen_random_uuid()

```
CREATE TABLE public.abandoned_url (
        id uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL
    );
```

Am I creating the dump file incorrectly? Could this be a bug in pg_dump?

Comment: `gen_random_uuid()` is a built-in function since PostgreSQL 13, so it lives in `pg_catalog` not in `public`. But if you use an older version, maybe you have a custom function `public.gen_random_uuid` in your source database. Can you clarify that in your question?

Comment: @david, did you ever come up with an answer here.  I'm having the same problem when attempting to restore w/ Heroku / PostGreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

As Postgres does exports with `if exists` in both commands, but you can make the database be dropped before inserting the backup

use

When you create the [dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html)

```
-c
--clean
```

> Output commands to clean (drop) database objects prior to outputting the commands for creating them. (Unless --if-exists is also specified, restore might generate some harmless error messages, if any objects were not present in the destination database.)

> This option is only meaningful for the plain-text format. For the archive formats, you can specify the option when you call pg_restore.

The same exists for the [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html), but if you used it in pg_dump you don't need it here

```
-c
--clean
```

> Clean (drop) database objects before recreating them. (Unless --if-exists is used, this might generate some harmless error messages, if any objects were not present in the destination database.)

Comment: The table does not exist in the database, the issue comes from pg_dumb adding `public` right before `gen_random_uuid() `  pg_dump is creating `id uuid DEFAULT public.gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL` instead of `id uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL`